# Snowflake SQL MAX over Partition by

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

QUERY # 1 (subquery):   I have a set of table records with columns A, B, C, D, E.  And I want to run a row count using columns A and B only with the following query  (and it works).

> SELECT  DISTINCT A,B,C,D,E , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A, B ) as ROWCOUNT  FROM TABLE

QUERY # 2 (main query) :
With the query # 1 results, I want to do a query to return the record with the MAX(ROWCOUNT).

I am thinking about using the SQL statement for the query #2 as my main query with query #1 as the subquery, but am struggling with this.   Helpful inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While you could use it as a sub query like you mentioned, you could just use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to fetch the "top" result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C,D,E , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A, B ) as ROWCOUNT FROM TABLE
ORDER BY 6 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What is the value of the DISTINCT?

Comment: It was copied from OP's query, but (assuming) the idea is to only return unique permutations of ABCD and E.

Answer (score 0):

Use [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify) to do a post aggregation filter. Then you need decide if your want 1 row, or all equal to max, and if you want that to be stable or unstable

The unstable single row version can be done with [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  A,B,C,D,E 
  ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A, B ) as ROWCOUNT 
FROM TABLE
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ROWCOUNT DESC) = 1
```